# Capybara, RSpec and Devise: any way to make integration tests faster by circumventing slow login and setting session directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, capybara

For nearly every integration test, a user has to be signed into Devise. This takes a lot of time, so I wondered whether there's a way to set up the user session without having to visit the login page, enter details, and press the login button.

Maybe there's a helper method built into Devise that immediately signs a given user in?

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the header of your spec file, insert `include Warden::Test::Helpers` and `Warden.test_mode!`, like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "AuthenticationPages" do

let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

before { login_as(user, scope: :user }
...
```

In above code, i used FactoryGirl to create an user. You can use other ways you like to create user. Then I login `user` by using method `login_as` . Then you can run any test and you can sure `user` has loged in. I think this is what you want, hope this help. You can see more details here [Test with capybara](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Test-with-Capybara).

**EDIT**

To make sure this works correctly you will need to reset warden after each test you can do this by calling

```
Warden.test_reset!
```

If for some reason you need to log out a logged in test user, you can use Warden's logout helper.

```
logout(:user)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great. However, I don't want to put it into every *_spec.rb file. I have a module `ValidUserRequestHelper` which is included into my request specs using `RSpec.configure do |c| { c.include ValidUserRequestHelper, :type => :request }`, and I tried putting `include Warden::Test::Helpers` and `Warden.test_mode!` into there, but this doesn't seem to work. Any idea?

Comment: Ooops, Spork didn't see my changes... After restarting it, it's working now. :-) Thanks.